# Spacing Characters appearing in bibtex output

Tags: bibtex, errors

BibTeX has been giving me a weird output.  I have the following entry in my `.bib` file:

```
@book{nathanson,
Author = {Melvyn B. Nathanson},
Title = {Additive Number Theory: the Classical Bases},
Publisher = {Springer-Verlag},
Year = {1996},
Place = {New York}
}
```

When I run BibTeX, the output for this entry is:

```
\bibitem{nathanson}
Melvyn~B. Nathanson.
\newblock {\em Additive Number Theory: the Classical Bases}.
\newblock Springer-Verlag, 1996.
```

Why is the `\em` appearing in the title of the book?  I have tried to use BibTeX several times, and this happens every time.  Every time I run `bibtex`, I have to go out of my way to delete this.  Can anyone explain how to get `bibtex` to stop inserting this `\em` command?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The `\em` command is inserted by the bibliographic style you're using; it makes the title appear in italics. Which one is it?

Comment: the `book` specs for `bibtex` (and probably for `biblates` too) specify that the title is to be set in italic.  `\em`, or "emphasis", is one method of specifying italic.

Comment: I was using "plain."

Comment: barbara:  Interesting.  But when I try to compile the document I get a bunch of "misplaced \crcr" errors in the compiler output, and when I delete the "\em" the document compiles correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that using `\em{}` changes to italic everything that goes after it, even if the text is outside the brackets.  However, `\emph{}` only italizes what is IN the brackets.

My bibtex output (.bbl file) has `\emph{}` and not `\em{}`.  I'm guessing that maybe there is a missing package for the `\bibliographystyle` you are using.  Try looking into your bibliography style documentation to see what's missing.

If this doesn't work, I recommend using *natbib*.  I has always worked well for me.